# how to use any proto with value is another proto

Tags: protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

I want to write tensorflow serving config file. But using Any proto.
how to use this.
platform_configs: {
    key: "tensorflow",
    value:  {
        source_adapter_config: {
            type_url: "type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.serving.SavedModelBundleSourceAdapterConfig"
            value: